# Multiple stores in if get store code?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

sorry stupid beginners questions. I am changing the layout of my  homepage based on the store code. Works fine with 1 store but how can I add multiple?

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'store1'){ ?>
```

works fine

but for example

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'store1 || store2'){ ?>
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your comparison is wrong your comparing like

decoding your code would be like

```
 'store1'=='store1 || store2'
```

That is completely wrong

do this way

```
 <?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'store1' || Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'store2'){ ?>
```

Comment: you are very fast mate. :D

Comment: @KingshukDeb  just some of the sec diff

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
if (in_array($storeCode, array('store1', 'store2')) {
    ...
```

or:

```
$storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
if ($storeCode == 'store1' || $storeCode == 'store2') {
    ...
```

Comment: Who in the world could down vote this answer?

Comment: Don't understand it too ... but hey, its OK :)

Answer (score -1):

This should also work and i think is better than [previous answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177118/6117). No need to use any extra variable at all.

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'store1' || Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'store2'){ ?>
```

Comment: Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand. - Martin Fowler

Comment: @Kingshuk I think i doesn't make a big difference. I think it's better readable and it also less function calls ...

Comment: @sv3n you can call Mage::app() as many times you want. Its a static function.It doesnt create any instance.I guess it wont affect the execution speed. But when you say readability then yes you can use an extra variable. But that too when you have lot of stores. Its just an example of 2 stores.

Comment: Just xhprof'ed for fun ... 8 vs 13 function calls (incl. Xhprof_Profiler calls) and 210 vs 290 microsec total wall time :)

Comment: Good to know. +1 useful.